# I am getting X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN refusal when i try to embed Google Groups forum in my site.

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, google-groups

I know there are many other questions related to this in stackoverflow. However my contention is i am using the code snippet provided by Google itself for the very purpose they state in their help page
 https://support.google.com/groups/answer/1191206?hl=en.

snippet: To embed a group in an external web page, copy and paste the following iFrame HTML into the web page's HTML source (make sure to change forum-name to your group name:

So i am not doing anything that google doesn't want me to do. Is this additional restriction put in by my browser? is this code snippet obsolete?

Thanks in advance for any insight related to this

Comment: I am unable to answer my question but i found the answer so here it is. This script works for embedding groups into a webpage The following code worked for me:

<iframe id="forum_embed" src="https://groups.google.com/forum/embed/?place=forum/NAMEOFMYFORUM#!forum/NAMEOFMYFORUM" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="700"></iframe>

Comment: Found the above solution here: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/does-anyone-know-how-to-embed-a-google-group-iframe-into-a-wp-page